# Error when compiling a C++ file with mongo-cxx-driver on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: c++, macos, mongodb, bson

The compiler is able to find all the drivers but gives a type traits error (incomplete type) when I'm trying to create a bsoncxx document using the << operator. It references to the c++ libraries so I have no reason to think that the mongo cxx driver would be installed incorrectly. The compiler doesn't complain about the preceding mongo operations either, just when I'm trying to create the bsoncxx document. Here is what I have:

Headers:

```
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/types.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/options/find.hpp>

using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
```

Code:

```
string start;
string end;

mongocxx::instance inst{};
mongocxx::client conn{};

auto db = conn["test"];

db["shortestpaths"].drop();
document index_spec{};
index_spec << "cost" << "-1"; // THE LINE THAT CAUSES THE ERROR
db["shortestpaths"].create_index(index_spec, {});

auto source = db["topology.src_ip"].find({});
for (auto&& doc : source){
    start = bsoncxx::to_json(doc);
    startVertex = std::stoi(start);

    auto dest = db["topology.dest_ip"].find({});
    for (auto&& field : dest){
        end = bsoncxx::to_json(field);
        destinationVertex = std::stoi(end);
        document filter;
        filter << "source" << start << "dest" << end; // if the line giving the error is commented out, this one gives the same error
        auto dest = db["shortestpaths"].find(filter);
        for (auto&& doc : dest){
            exists = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (startVertex != destinationVertex && !exists){
            YenTopKShortestPathsAlg yenAlg(my_graph, my_graph.get_vertex(startVertex),
                my_graph.get_vertex(destinationVertex));

            while(yenAlg.has_next())
            {
                // TODO: Add mongoDB query here to add the entry
                yenAlg.next()->PrintOut(outFile);
                outFile << '\n';
            }
        }
        exists = false;
    }
```

Makefile:

```
CXX=c++
 CFLAGS=-c --std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/local/mongo-cxx-driver/include/mongocxx/v0.3 -I/usr/local/mongo-cxx-driver/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/mongo-cxx-driver/include/bsoncxx/v0.3 -I/usr/local/mongo-cxx-driver/include/libbson-1.0
 LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/mongo-cxx-driver/lib -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx pkg-config
 SOURCES=DijkstraShortestPathAlg.cpp Graph.cpp MainP.cpp YenTopKShortestPathsAlg.cpp
 OBJECTS=DijkstraShortestPathAlg.o Graph.o MainP.o YenTopKShortestPathsAlg.o
 EXECUTABLE=algorithm

 all: $(EXECUTABLE)

 $(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(LDFLAGS)

 $(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCES)

clean:
    @rm -f $(PROGRAMS) *.o core
```

When I run make, I get:

```
In file included from MainP.cpp:5:
In file included from
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/limits:110:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:7    94:59: error: 
      incomplete type
          'bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::value_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::key_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::closed_context>
      >' used in type trait expression
    : public integral_constant<bool, __is_base_of(_Bp, _Dp)> {};
                                                          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:1052:    5: note: 
      in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::is_base_of<std::__1::ios_base,
          bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::value_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::key_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::closed_context>
      > >' requested here
    is_base_of<ios_base, _Stream>::value,
    ^
/usr/local/mongo-cxx-driver/include/bsoncxx/v0.3/bsoncxx/builder/stream/value_context.hpp:63:86:     note: 
      while substituting deduced template arguments into function template
      'operator<<' [with _Stream =
          bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::value_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::key_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::closed_context>
      >, _Tp = int]
  ...decltype(std::declval<value_context>() << 1 << "str")>::value,
                                            ^
MainP.cpp:67:16: note: in instantiation of template class
          'bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::value_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::key_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::closed_context>
      >' requested here
    index_spec << "cost" << "-1";
               ^
/usr/local/mongo-cxx-driver/include/bsoncxx/v0.3/bsoncxx/builder/stream/value_context.hpp:31:7:     note: 
      definition of
          'bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::value_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::key_context<bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::closed_context>
      >' is not complete until the closing '}'
class value_context {
                    ^
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This code cannot be easily copy and pasted into a file and compiled, so it is hard to work with. Please re-post a complete code body that exhibits the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing `bsoncxx::builder::stream::document` with `bsoncxx::document`.

Please read: [Handling BSON in the new driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Handling-BSON-in-the-new-driver)

Here's an example how it should be used:

```
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;

auto index_spec = document{} << "cost" << "-1" << finalize;
db["shortestpaths"].create_index(index_spec.view(), {});
```